# Exponential distribution with mean $\mu$ and probability question

Tags: probability

[image]

im on the last part and my attempt was to:

find $P(|\bar{X_n} - \mu| < 0.01) > 0.99$ but in the solutions showed the equation is $P(|\bar{X_n} - \mu|/\mu < 0.01 ) > 0.99$ why do we have to divide through my $\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample mean $\bar{X_n}$ being within $1\%$ of $\mu$ means 
$$|\bar{X_n} - \mu| \lt 0.01 \mu$$ and to remove $\mu$ from the right hand side requires dividing both sides by positive $\mu$ to give $$\dfrac{|\bar{X_n} - \mu|}{\mu} \lt 0.01$$ (you seem to have an extra $0$ in your expression.)

I suspect the question is asking for a large sample Gaussian approximation.

Comment: I thought the sample mean being within 1% of $\mu$ means the absolute value between the sample mean and $\mu$ is simply less than 1% then $\bar{X}$ is within $1$% of $\mu$. Why do you have $0.01\mu$

Comment: "$1\%$" is another way of writing "$0.01$", so "$1\%$ of $\mu$" can be written as "$0.01\mu$"

Comment: No I understand that, but it says that the sample mean is within 1 per cent of $\mu$. If I say I'm within 10 km of the supermarket then surely that means the distance between me (the sample mean) and the supermarket ($\mu$) is less than 10 km? This is what I took it as, and is why I wrote $|\bar{X_n} - \mu|  < 0.01 \mu$

Comment: I take your point about the wording, but it was probably intended to mean that the sample mean was within $\mu \pm 1\%\mu$ rather than $\mu \pm 1\%$.  Otherwise the units (whatever they are) do not match in the addition.

Comment: I see, could you expand a little on the units not matching in the addition please?

Comment: Think it through: If a target length is $200$ meters, then a quantity that is within $1$ percent would be within how many meters of $200$?

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit of intuition to Henry's explanation: If someone guesses your weight to within $1$ percent, we intend that to be $1$ percent *of your weight*.  So if I weigh $70$ kg, then a satisfactory guess need only be within $70/100 = 0.7$ kg, not $0.01$ kg.

To proceed with the question, one must derive an expression for the variance of a single exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\mu$—let this variance be called $\sigma^2$—then apply the central limit theorem to the sum of a large number of such variables.

Let $n$ be the number of i.i.d. random variables, each exponentially distributed with mean $\mu$, needed to satisfy the condition in the problem; we must solve for $n$.

As mentioned above, let the expression you derived in part (i) be denoted $\sigma^2$.  The variance of the sum of $n$ random variables is then $n\sigma^2$, and the standard deviation of the sum is the square root of that, or $\sqrt{n} \sigma$.  The standard deviation of the *average* of the random variables—i.e., the sample mean—is then that divided by $n$, or $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

We presume (and can verify upon determining what $n$ is) that $n$ is large enough to invoke the central limit theorem with negligible loss of accuracy, so the rest of the problem involves determining how many standard deviations (two-sided) contain $0.99$ of a normal distribution.  Let this number be denoted $K$; then

$$
\frac{K\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\mu}{100}
$$
$$
\sqrt{n} = \frac{100K\sigma}{\mu}
$$
$$
n = \frac{10000K^2\sigma^2}{\mu^2}
$$